# Parametrizing solutions of diophantine $8x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ gone wrong. Where's the mistake?

Tags: number-theory

So I have
$$
8x^2 + y^2 = z^2.
$$
Dividing both parts by $z$ yields
$$
8X^2+Y^2 = 1,
$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are rational. Point $(0, -1)$ is on the ellipse, so I parametrize with $(X, tX - 1)$, where $t$ is arbitrary rational. Plugging it into equation yields
$$
8X^2 + t^2X^2 - 2tX + 1 = 1,
$$
$$
X = \frac{2t}{t^2+8} \implies Y = tX - 1 = \frac{t^2-8}{t^2+8}.
$$
Setting $t = p/q$, we thus have
$$
X = \frac{2pq}{p^2+8q^2}, Y = \frac{p^2-8q^2}{p^2+8q^2},
$$
so that
$$
x = 2pqk, y = (p^2 - 8q^2)k, z = (p^2 + 8q^2)k.
$$
The trouble is that $8\times15^2 + 41^2 = 59^2$, and there is no way you can make $2pqk$ equal to 15.

Where's the error? Thanks.

Comment: There's some coprimality issue here, it's not clear to me that $X, Y$ are reduced fractions identically. Taking $p=2, q=2k+1$ then the fractions have reduction, even though $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $p$ is even, then all the terms $2pq, p^2+8q^2, p^2-8q^2$ are divisible by (at least) $4$, and by cancelling it out, one can obtain new solutions. The list will probably be complete if you allow $k$ to take values in $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}=\{\frac{z}{2^m}\; | \; z \in \mathbb{Z}, m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ whenever this makes sense (actually, $\frac{1}{8}\mathbb{Z}$ should be enough).

(Note that there should not be any problem with other primes than $2$, assuming $p, q$ are (WLOG) taken coprime - whenever a prime $r\neq 2$ divides $2pq$, then it wlog divides $p,$ hence it divides $p^2$, but not $p^2 \pm 8q^2$.)

Answer (score -1):

A parameterization can be found as follows. I do not know if it is complete, but it does work:

$8x^2 + y^2 = 2(2x)^2 + y^2$

$2X^2 + Y^2 = Z^2$ is given by $(X,Y,Z) = (2ab, b^2 - 2a^2, b^2 + 2a^2)$

$X = 2x, y = Y, z = Z$

Thus $x = ab, y = b^2 - 2a^2, z = b^2 + 2a^2$ parameterizes $8x^2 + y^2 = z^2$

$(x,y,z) = (ab, b^2 - 2a^2, b^2 + 2a^2)$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).